# Regex for mustache-style double braces?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using Mustache-style tags inside of AngularJS. What's the best regex to use to return an array of *just* the text inside the mustache braces?

Sample data:

```
"This could {{be }} a {{ string.with.dots_and_underscores }} of {{ mustache_style}} words which {{could}} be pulled."
```

Expected output:

```
['be','string.with.dots_and_underscores','mustache_style','could']
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you use a global search with `.match`, JavaScript won't give the capture groups in its array output. As such, you need to do it twice: Once to find the `{{...}}` pairs, then again to extract the names from within them:

```
str.match(/{{\s*[\w\.]+\s*}}/g)
   .map(function(x) { return x.match(/[\w\.]+/)[0]; });
```

Comment: Was just about to suggest adding `[0]` to the match so that you get an array of strings instead of an array of arrays before the edit. Nice

Comment: nit: this regex is a bit too lenient about the dot notation, allowing non-valid mustache variable names like `.variable` or `context..variable`. Here's a stricter regex: `{{\s*\w+(?:\.\w+)*\s*}}`

Answer (score 13):

### Mod of *Douglas Crockford*'s `String.prototype.supplant`

This will interpolate any `{param}` you have between handleBars (`{}`). I know this answer is somewhat extensive, but I assumed the question was probably regarding *interpolation* -- either way, I'd advise the reader to study the regex, regardless.

```
clear();

function interpolate(str) {
    return function interpolate(o) {
        return str.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g, function (a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
        });
    }
}

var terped = interpolate('The {speed} {color} fox jumped over the lazy {mammal}')({
    speed: 'quick',
    color: 'brown',
    mammal: 'dog'
});

console.log(terped);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 8):

You could try doing this with `exec()` instead:

```
var list = [],
    x = '"This could {{be }} a {{ string }} of {{ mustache_style}} words which {{could}} be pulled."',
    re = /{{\s*([^}]+)\s*}}/g,
    item;

while (item = re.exec(x))
    list.push(item[1]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this

```
/{{\s?([^}]*)\s?}}/
```

The values would be in first group (you know, not the 0-group, the 1-group :))

One more point - this regex is captures *everything* between `{{` and `}}`, so all the punctuation marks, braces, dots, etc. If you need only words (possibly separated by underscore or whitespace) this would be more useful for you:

```
/{{\s?[\w\s]*\s?}}/
```

Comment: Actually, /g is kind of useless here, `*` is greedy by default

Comment: In javascript land, I get this as the output: ["{{be }}", "be "]. With the /g, it was capturing everything as mustache-expressions... how do I get access to the 1-group? Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex

Comment: OK I updated... so no whitespace, but dots and underscores. :)

Comment: sorry, I missed the `^}` part when I commented

Answer (score 3):

I really liked the answer @Cody provided, but ran into a scope issue if you wanted to make the object you pass more of a real object and not just a list, so I found an eval trick to change the scope so I thought I would share it.

```
function interpolate(str) {
    return function interpolate(o) {
        return str.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g, function (a, b) {
            let r
            with(o){
              r = eval(b)
            }
            return r
        });
    }
}

var terped = interpolate('The {speed} {fox.color} {mammal[2]} jumped over the lazy {mammal[0]}')({
    speed: 'quick',
    fox: {
      color: 'brown'
    },
    mammal: ['dog', 'cat', 'fox']
});

console.log(terped)
```